# Prestashop migration procedure

Tags: migration, prestashop

I have a client who wants to move their hosting provider and we have successfully cloned exact copy of original server to the new hosting provider's server. We want to use different domain name *staging.copiedsite.com* to creating staging environment to check everything works fine, then we want to flicker it back to original DNS (www.actualsite.com). My question is, how do you configure the site to work with staging domain name? I am going to basically find all database record that says "www.actualsite.com" and replace it with "staging.copiedsite.com". Is that all it needs? Is there any configuration text file that I need to edit? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shall change the domain in `BackOffice` > `Preferences` > `SEO & URLs`. This will update configuration in database and your `.htaccess` file (For some obscure reason you might have to save this page two times so that the `.htaccess` file is overwritten).

Also some CMS pages and modules can use absolute URLs so changing all those values by querying the database is a good idea.

Basically that's all you need.

Comment: Thanks for helpful info, and I will make sure to go through that procedure as well.